# arraylist sorting using for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop

Below is my sorting program. Please tell me the logic in this program. I'm getting confusion in the positions of `i` and `j`.

```
public class Ascending {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[] arVal = {20, 45, 34, 89, 34, 42};
    int i;
    int y;
    int temp;

    System.out.println("Ascending Order is:");

    for (i = 0; i < arVal.length; i++) {


        for (y = i + 1; y < arVal.length; y++) {

            temp = arVal[i];

            if (arVal[i] > arVal[y]) {

                temp = arVal[i];
                arVal[i] = arVal[y];
                arVal[y] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arVal.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(arVal[i]);

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It compares each element with all the others `20 with 45 34 89 etc` end if 20 is larger it
swaps places. So after the first iteration nothing happens because 20 is the smaller one.
When i = 1, 45 is larger than 34 therefor 20, **34**, **45**, 89, 34, 42 and now compares
**34** not 45 with 89, nothing, with 34 nothing with 42 nothing. i = 2, 45 with etc...

pseudocode:

```
arVal[0] = min{20 45 34 89 34 42} = 20  
arVal[1] = min{45 34 89 34 42} = 34  
arVal[2] = min{45 89 34 42} = 34  
arVal[3] = min{45 89 42} = 42
arVal[4] = min{45 89} = 45  
arVal[5] = 89
```